# Compatibility Glassfish and Eclipse for WebApplications

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I tried some tutorials for creating Web Applications using Eclipse Neon 3, Hibernate, Spring and `Glassfish` server 4.1. I downloaded `Glassfish` Tools via Eclipse Marketplace, but I don't know how to solve my error about not publishing via `Glassfish` server the project. Could you tell me what is the compatibility between them? `Glassfish` tools don't refer to the `Glassfish` server 4.1, just 4. 
I read another questions and tried the solutions found there but it didn't work.

The error is: Could not publish to the server.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 cannot Deploy [project_name]
 deploy is failling = java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse Project---> Clean --> Clean all projects---> ok.
Try to run the project Run as server.

Comment: Yes sometimes this creates problem .apart from this 
When adding a new server, do not add any web application to the server. Just add a server with no web module. After server was added, right click on server and "Add and Remove". This should now work.

Comment: Thank you! I did that but it didn't work for me. I changed the server from Glassfish to Tomcat and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Glassfish Server -> Properties -> GlassFish -> Tick on the Use JAR Archives for deployment. (at the bottom)

This might work.

And also if you get any domain related errors, just change the location of the installed Glassfish server from C: drive to other drives as Glassfish needs administrative access if placed in C: drive. So better place in other drives.